In supabase, want to read specific data from table when user not logged in?
i need to read specific data from table if not logged in also
I was diabled RLS policy, added new policy like this
alter policy "new"
on "public"."palettes"
to anon
using (
true
);
i need to read specific data from table if not logged in also
